# How to see the result of validation in Typescript?

Tags: validation, typescript, aurelia

I am new in Aurelia and I want to see the result of validation. I have the following code:

```
    public submit() {
    this.controller.validate()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.valid) {
          // validation succeeded
        } else {
          // validation failed
        }
      });
  }
```

How to see the result's report. How to use alert() for this purpose? For example

> alert(result.getAlertText())

does not work!!!! What is the alternative?

Comment: print to the console with console.log('valid/unvalid') perhaps?

Comment: add alert within if else?

Comment: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/5

Comment: As you know, result is an object. How can I find the type of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in HTML side, I added the following code in HTML file:

```
<ul if.bind="controller.errors">
<li repeat.for="error of controller.errors">
  ${error.message}
</li>
```

Now, I can see the type of error.

Answer (score 0):

See: [source here](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/validate-result.ts)

So that would be:

> alert(result.message)

Comment: Then share more code, give us more context. Your controller, views, etc